# How to fetch data from Amplify's GraphQL API and store it in a React's context variable

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, graphql, aws-amplify, react-context

I am using React native and I have a context variable `post`, it has an attribute called `name` and I have defined a function called `onChange` to set it.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const PostContext = React.createContext({
  content: "",
  onChange: (newPostContent: string) => {},
});

export const PostContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  const postChangeHandler = (newPostContent: string) => {
    setContent(newPostContent);
  };

  return (
    <PostContext.Provider
      value={{ content, onChange: postChangeHandler }}
    >
      {children}
    </PostContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default PostContext;
```

Now I have a page on which I want to fetch a post from Amplify's GraphQL API and set its content to my context variable, so I can use it on other pages.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { API, graphqlOperations} from "aws-amplify";

import PostContext from "./context/post-context";

const post = useContext(PostContext);

const fetchPost = async () => {
  const {data: {getPost: { postContent },},} = await API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(`
      query GetPost {
        getPost(id: "${some post Id}") {
          content
        }
      }
    `)
    );

   post.onChange(postContent)
}


useEffect(()=>{
  fetchPost()
}, [])

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(post.content)
}, [post])
```

What I expect is that in the async function, the execution is blocked until `postContent` (because of the `await` and then it's value is assigned to the context variable, or its update is schedualed (that's why I have also included a `useEffect` to `console.log` the value of `post.content`. But it is not updated and its value remains an empty screen. Can somebody help me with this? I am learning React native how this work, so a detailed answer that lets me know what I am doing wrong is appreciated.